# Superfish Menu OnHover instead of OnClick

Tags: 7, navigation, javascript

I'm in the process of redesigning my site and have decided on using Superfish menus.

Well after installing it (and I've made sure every library is included) I have run into the issue that the dropdowns only appear after clicking the parent, rather than hovering.

Is this something that needs to be selected in the settings or am I missing something somewhere else?

I've also tries using jQuery verions 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.10 as tests from other posts who have suggested it, but nothing has worked.

If anyone can provide any help, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: I can't test this, so I would need a link to your side to be able to help you. Or you could try and wait for someone else that has a site with Superfish. I wish you all the best!

Comment: @ChrisHappy - here is the url: http://www.egyptianstudysociety.com, you'll see the menu at the top (at the moment it's fixed just to differentiate the current and future menus). I'd appreciate any help you can help!! Thanks! Matt